# List.Contains based on a property of a list item

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, filter

I have a List `myList` of `MyObjects`.  Is it possible to check if `myList` contains a particular `myObject` based on a property of `myObject` in VB.NET?  In C#, you'd something similar to this right:

```
myList.Exists(myObject => myObject.property1 == 3)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm sure you could use `myList.Exists` in VB.NET too, just with its lambda expression syntax.

However, the more general way is to use the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) LINQ operator, with the overload that takes a predicate. For example:

```
myList.Any(Function(myObject) myObject.property1 = 3)
```

Personally I prefer to use LINQ operators unless the more specific `List<T>` method provides a significant advantage for some reason.

EDIT:

If you need to access the object afterwards, just use:

```
Dim foo = myList.FirstOrDefault(Function(myObject) myObject.property1 = 3)
If (foo Is Not Nothing) Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks.  If there is a match, how can I then access the matched element?  Do I use singleOrDefault?

Comment: @Prabhu: Or `FirstOrDefault`. I suggest you use that to start with - there's no point in finding it, and then looking again.

Comment: Thanks!  Actually I need to access the item and also edit a property.  If I edit foo, how do I then update the list with the updated foo?

Comment: @Prabhu: Assuming `MyObject` is a class, you'll be updating the object which the list element refers to anyway. It's *really* important that you understand how reference types work in .NET. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html

Comment: I get "Is operator does not accept operands of type integer. Operands must be reference or nullable types" when trying to do the "Is Not Nothing" check.  I verified that myObject is a class. Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It's roughly the same, except VB.NET has a different syntax for lambda expressions:

```
myList.Exists(Function(myObject) myObject.property1 = 3)
```